# MVC Page to Accept Different Query Arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a results view that displays a list of items.

In some cases, I want to display items where one field matches the query argument. In other cases, I want to display items where another field matches the query argument. And so on.

How can I provide arguments to my controller/view so that it knows what kind of results to get? I could write multiple controllers, but then I get the error that "Type 'MyType' already defines a member called 'MyMethod' with the same parameter type."

Ideally, I could find a way to do this without creating additional routes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you want to do the following:

- Reutilize a view, so that you don't have to make one for each query.
- Use the same method name on a controller so that you don't have a different url for each query.

You could add an extra parameter to your method so that you can perform a different query depending on the value of the extra parameter:

```
public class QueryController
{
    private enum QueryType
    {
        TypeA = 0,
        TypeB = 1,
        TypeC = 2
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void ShowResults(QueryType type, string criteria)
    {
        /*
        * Code here to make the query using the field you want,
        * depending on the "type" parameter e.g.
        *
        * switch (type)
        * {
        *      case TypeA:
        *           model = db.Items.Where(x => x.FieldA == criteria);
        *           break;
        *      case TypeB:
        *           model = db.Items.Where(x => x.FieldB == criteria);
        *           break;
        * }
        */

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Another thing, don't worry about the routes, the default route {controller}/{method}/{id} doesn't demand that you have to specify the URLs in that strict way. This is a valid URL for the previous example:

http://www.example.com/App/Query/ShowResults?type=1&criteria=foo

The default MVC binder will use the parameter names in the URL to bind their values to the parameters of your method.

I hope I didn't misunderstood your question.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm completely new to MVC and really don't get when I can add arguments will nilly like that. But, in fact, I was able to get this working very easily. (Still not quite sure why.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With MVC, query string values map to parameter values (and Routes are used to create custom mappings).

There are special exceptions though.  If a parameter is a `FormCollection` (which is basically just a `Dictionary<string>`), then all un-mapped query string values will be passed in.

So, you can create a single `Action` that takes in all parameters:

```
// GET: MyController/ViewList?name=aaa&field1=foo&field2=bar
public ActionResult ViewList(string name, FormCollection otherFields) {
    foreach (var field in otherFields) {
        switch (field.Key.ToLower()) {
            case "field1":
                // Filter field1 based on field.Value
            case "field2":
                // Filter field2 based on field.Value
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Similarly, you could also have no parameters, and just use `this.Request.QueryString` to inspect the query string values.  However, I prefer the `FormCollection` method because it makes it clear that I expect other parameters.